safe-core not able to access app.safe.global
not able to access app.safe.global in dubai since morning. only this website is a problem all other websites are opening. whats the issue and how to solve this its working with a vpn. Error message received: Server not available. Wht is this happening, how to solve this?

Hey there, what exactly do you mean by safe-core? Are you using the API or the SDK? Maybe you are referring to Safe{Wallet} (app.safe.global) instead, in which case, please feel free to open a support ticket here: https://help.safe.global/en/
